# Add registry access rule to key to which I've no access but I'm an administrator

Tags: c#, security, registry

I'm trying to add some access rules to registry key to which I've no rights, but I'm an administrator and using `"Run as administrator"` command at right mouse button menu.
Unfortunately exception is being thrown (`System.UnauthorizedAccessException`).
When running `regedit.exe` as administrator I can change rights to this key w/o any problems.
How to add any access rule to this key in my application?

```
RegistryKey root = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\some_key", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
RegistrySecurity security = new RegistrySecurity();
SecurityIdentifier sec = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
RegistryAccessRule rule = new RegistryAccessRule(sec, RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.QueryValues, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow);
security.AddAccessRule(rule);
root.SetAccessControl(security);
root.Close();
```

Comment: Old thread, but for those who find this thread (as I did) see work-around solution at:
[S.O. setting owner on a registry key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742115/asp-net-vb-setting-owner-on-a-registry-key)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `GetAccessControl`() method to get a `RegistrySecurity` object:

```
RegistryKey root = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\some_key", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
RegistrySecurity security = root.GetAccessControl();
```

You probably get the exception because you are trying to overwrite the security rules, instead of modifying them.

Comment: This object (key) has no security rules set, and inheritance is disabled, so how to get any? Even if I remove all lines of code except RegistryKey root = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(...) and root.Close(); the program crashes too.

Comment: @daftu, perhaps the problem is in @"SOFTWARE\some_key". Try to first get the SOFTWARE key with write permission, using the OpenSubKey(). And then call CreateSubKey on the returned key.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setaccesscontrol.aspx) is pretty clear:

> `UnauthorizedAccessException`: The
>   current RegistryKey object represents
>   a key with access control security,
>   and the caller does not have
>   RegistryRights.ChangePermissions
>   rights.

See also the documentation for [`RegistryRights`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.registryrights%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: You're saying it is not possible in my case to change/set access rule for this object?

Comment: @daftu: Of course I 'm not saying that. `regedit` does it, why shouldn't you be able to?

Comment: So please give me suggestion how to do this, because the documentation is't so clear for me (like 4 you)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I've encountered this problem before. I found that you need to first open the key with **RegistryRights.ChangePermissions**, then you can modify the access control.

Try opening the key like this:

```
    RegistryKey root = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\some_key",
RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.ChangePermissions);
```

And then modifying the AccessControl rules.